SymmetricDS time-based sync
I'm trying to configure time-based sync on SymmetricDS, currently I'm using trigger based sync for PostgreSQL to Oracle, but since it's overflowing the database on insert, updates there's another possible option to run sync using additional column like 'last-update'.
On https://symmetricds.sourceforge.net/doc/3.15/html/user-guide.html says we can configure it using the sym_trigger table's column named 'TIME_BASED_COLUMN_NAME' so it says configure it like
https://www.jumpmind.com/blog/blog/how-to/time-based-replication-symmetricds/
But I really don't understand how it's checking it's changes, how to configure it on table, Anyone have practical experience on it?
My current trigger is:
INSERT INTO sym_trigger 
(trigger_id, 
 source_schema_name, 
 source_table_name, 
 channel_id, 
 sync_on_update, 
 sync_on_insert, 
 sync_on_delete, 
 sync_on_update_condition, 
 sync_on_insert_condition, 
 sync_on_delete_condition, 
 last_update_time, 
 create_time, 
 sync_on_incoming_batch
 )
VALUES 
 ('sync_on_public', 
  'public', 
  'table_name', 
  'default', 
   1, 
   1, 
   1, 
  '1=1', 
  '1=1', 
  '1=1', 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  1
  );

